# Pagekite used with Influxdb RPCs

Tags: influxdb, pagekite

Does anybody know how to integrate Pagekite so that it can listen on InfluxDB RPCs on port 8088?

I'm trying to use the raw protocol:

- frontend seems to start listening on requests on 8088.
- backend doesn't look to be picking up the calls.